# The system cannot find the file specified error on creating certificate for localhost using openssl

Tags: openssl, windows-10, command-prompt

I am trying to generate a certificate for localhost using below command in command prompt and I am getting 'The system cannot find the file specified'
Can some one help me to resolve this.

```
openssl req -x509 -out localhost.crt -keyout localhost.key \
-days 365 \
-newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -sha256 \
-subj '/CN=localhost' -extensions EXT -config <( \
 printf "[dn]\nCN=localhost\n[req]\ndistinguished_name = dn\n[EXT]\nsubjectAltName=DNS:localhost\nkeyUsage=digitalSignature\nextendedKeyUsage=serverAuth")
```

Comment: The output of `openssl req` is a CSR, not a certificate (.crt). Off topic.

Answer (score 0):

The above command usually works for Linux systems, Since, you are talking about Windows 10, May be it is wise to use IIS manager to create an ssl certificate for localhost, a good working example would be, [here](https://www.sslshopper.com/article-how-to-create-a-self-signed-certificate-in-iis-7.html)